# WSO2 Composite Application Project doesn't show any dependency

Tags: eclipse, wso2, activiti, composite-application

I am new to WSO2 and I am trying to create an HelloWorld process following this guide: https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS360/Creating+a+BPMN+Process

The problem is that when i try to create a Composite Application Project, no available dependencies are shown (as you can see in the screenshot)

[New Composite Application Project screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MjHE.png)

I'm using Eclipse JavaEE Mars2 with the tooling plug-in installed and Activiti Eclipse Designer plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Installing the [BPS Tooling plug-in](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS360/Installing+the+BPS+Tooling+Plug-In#InstallingtheBPSToolingPlug-In-Installtheplug-inwithpre-packagedEclipse) with changed location `http://builder1.us1.wso2.org/~developerstudio/developer-studio-kernel/4.1.0/bps-tooling/releases/3.6.0/` fixes the problem.