# WSO2 Composite Application Project doesn't show any dependencies in the wizard

Tags: config, wso2

I am aware that this is very similar to a question posted over a year ago:

[WSO2 Composite Application Project doesn't show any dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906384/wso2-composite-application-project-doesnt-show-any-dependency)

I am also following the WSO2 tutorial.  I have downloaded the 'and the kitchen sink' version of eclipse from WSO2 and EI.

I tried the suggested solution in that other thread (downloading various versions of P2).  All of them failed because the components were older than the ones I already had installed.

My platform is Win 10.

I'd be happy to switch to oxygen (most recent version of eclipse - the WSO2 one is Mars 2) if that would help.

The 'artifact' project which you create as the previous step is empty except for a pom.xml file.  So perhaps there are some missing steps?

Here's that POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.HelloWorldServiceTask_Artifact</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloWorldServiceTask_Artifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <name>HelloWorldServiceTask_Artifact</name>
  <description>HelloWorldServiceTask_Artifact</description>
  <properties>
    <CApp.type>lib/library/bundle</CApp.type>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.HelloWorldServiceTask</groupId>
      <artifactId>HelloWorldServiceTask</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <id>wso2-nexus</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>wso2-maven2-repository-1</id>
      <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <id>wso2-nexus</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>wso2-maven2-repository-1</id>
      <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>HelloWorldServiceTask_Artifact</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Name>HelloWorldServiceTask_Artifact</Bundle-Name>
            <Export-Package>org.wso2.bpmn.helloworld.v1</Export-Package>
            <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <buildcommands />
          <projectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.library.project.nature</projectnature>
          </projectnatures>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Thanks and apologies again.